# Неполадки с винчестером

Tags: linux

С винтом что-то не то. Я так понял он не монтируется. A если установить windows?

Comment: Добрый день. Как вы определили что диск не монтируется?

Answer (score 2):

если с винтом что-то не то, то переустановка системы Вам не поможет...
Возмите специальные программы/загрузочные диски от производителя и потестите/пошаманьте винт ими. Так же существуют общеупотребительные (имеется ввиду не от производителей железа) загрузочные диски с тестирующими/восстанавливающими прогами.
Естественно, сначала необходимо все слить с него.

Answer (score -1):

Протестируйте жёсткий диск на битые секторы. 
Составить список битых секторов можно с помощью команды badblocks.
Делается это так:

sudo badblocks -v /dev/hda1 > ~/badblocks.list
Где /dev/hda1 — это раздел диска, что вы хотите проверить.

Желательно делать проверку в однопользовательском режиме, если это не внешний диск. Тогда его просто стоит отмонтировать.

После этого мы можем запустить утилиту fsck, явно указав ей список битых секторов для того, чтобы она их отметила как «битые» и попыталась восстановить с них данные.
Делается это так:

sudo fsck -t ext4 -l ~/badblocks.list /dev/hda1
Где ext4 — это тип файловой системы нашего раздела диска, а /dev/hda1 — сам раздел диска.

fsck выведет статус проверки и может спросить как поступать в том или ином случаи.
Пример вывода такой:

Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Check reference counts.
Pass 5: Checking group summary information.

/dev/hda1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/hda1: 11/360 files, 63/1440 blocks